# Get attributes from post data in PHP

Tags: php, post, attributes, tags

I'm using laravel to create a simple social network. Users can type @ in the post area to get a list of their friends to mention them. Every mention in a link like this (using zurb/tribute from github)

```
<a type="mention" href="/user/Jordan" title="Jordan">Jordan</a>
```

Normal links other than mentions won't have `type='mention'`

Now when I get the post and insert it into the database I need to get a list of users mentioned in the post. I'm looking for links which have the `type ='mention'` and if there's any I want to get the title of everyone to insert into the notification system. What PHP code do I need to add in this `if` statement?

```
if(stristr(request('post'),' type="mention" ')){

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from using an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree), your best bet would be to either use DOM on PHP Side, e.g.:

```
$string = '<a type="mention" href="/user/Jordan" title="Jordan">Jordan</a>';
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($string);
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query("//a[@type='mention']") as $a) {
    $href = $a->getAttribute('href');
    $title = $a->getAttribute('title');
    echo sprintf("Found mention of %s with href of %s\n", $title, $href);
}
```

However, I probably wouldn't be sending the A node back to the server. You should consider working out some way to make it a display-only feature implemented on the browser side, and simply send the "@jordan" string back to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the notice and code but I go this "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DOMDocument' not found"

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. Both DOMDocument and DOMXPath are both in the standard library, meaning you need to either include them at the top of your file, with the other "use" statements, such as: "use DOMDocument" or change the code to be \DOMDocument. Will update my answer now.

Comment: works great thanks a lot. The way I send it as a link is to allow other users to click n the mention and get redirected to that user's page or perform any other action. I'll try to find a way to send it as @name.